# UIActionSheet, store id object for each cell is possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

For my needs in my app what I need is store `id` object in each button and not to be relying on `buttonIndex`.
I've no idea how can I do it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would suggest subclassing UIButton to store whatever "`id`" object you want, but we don't have access to the internals of "`UIActionSheet`".  It's always using non-subclassable buttons.  You'll have to store a separate NSArray of "`id`" objects and use the button index to refer to the object in your separate NSArray.

B.T.W., UIAlertController is deprecated as of iOS 8, in favor of using the new [UIAlertController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIAlertController) class.  And you can set up [`UIAlertActions` with buttons that correspond to title and a "`handler:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertAction_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIAlertAction/actionWithTitle:style:handler:) block (i.e. you could store your "`id`" object in the handler).